# Do Electrum Wallets accept BCH?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I bought BCH from Bitcoin.com and provided an Electrum Wallet Address. The money did not arrive and Simplex, who arranged the transaction, advised that Electrum Wallets are only BTC even though the app does not mention this. Simplex sent me a link comprised of a http address on Bitcoin.com's website and the wallet address I originally provided which takes me to where my BCH is sitting but I do not know how to regain control of it and send it to a new BCH wallet. Bitcoin.com do not respond to emails. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's exclusively about BCH not Bitcoin.

Answer (score 5):

Electrum is a Bitcoin only application. This is directly stated by Electrum where it says it is a Bitcoin wallet. It does not say that it is a wallet for any other cryptocurrency. You cannot use Electrum for Bitcoin Cash.

To get your Bitcoin Cash, you will need to export your private keys from your Electrum wallet and import them into a Bitcoin Cash wallet. This may be easiest to do with Electron Cash which is a fork of Electrum but modified to work with Bitcoin Cash.

Answer (score -1):

Simple. Download electroncash on your PC. Make a duplicate of your current wallet file and save it on your desktop. Open electroncash  and when it asks for wallet file to open, click browse and choose the duplicate file. Your coins should show up.